# How to return coordinates from a service in angularJS / cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm having trouble passing the data from my geolocationService to my weatherCtrl. I want to pass the position in my controller so I can send my openweather api's request.

Also, i have troubles understanding how is the data stored in services and how to use them correctly.

Here are my js files.

**geolocationService.js**

```
angular.module('app').service('geolocationService', function() {
geolocationSuccess = function(position){
    alert(
    'Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
    'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
    'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
    'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
    'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
    'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
    'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
    'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
    return position;
}
geolocationError = function(error) {
    alert(
    'code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
    'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
this.getGeolocation = function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,geolocationError);
}});
```

**weatherCtrl.js**

```
    angular.module('app').controller('weatherCtrl',['$scope', '$http', 'cityService', 'geolocationService',
    function($scope, $http , cityService, geolocationService){
        $scope.searchCity = function () {
            var apiKey = "****";
            var apiLang = "en"
            var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q="+$scope.city+"&APPID="+apiKey+"&units=metric&lang="+apiLang;
            $http.get(url).success(httpSuccess).error(function(){
                alert("Erreur : données non récupérées");
            });
        }
        $scope.Math = Math;
        httpSuccess = function(response){
            $scope.weather = response;
        }
        $scope.setCity = function (city){
            cityService.set(city);
        }
        $scope.geolocate = function (){
            $scope.position = geolocationService.getGeolocation();
        }
    }
]);
```

So when I call geolocate(), the geolocationSuccess function is called but I don't know how to return the position correctly.

Comment: it is returning the value from position. What do you mean by "correctly"?

Answer (score 0):

You return the position in your geolocationSuccess function, but didn't assign it to any variable.

because navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is an async call.
ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

so I do geolocationService.setGeolocation first, you can bind it to any other function, just be aware of async issue.
I add a Promise way to solve async issue, check the bottom.

**weatherCtrl.js**

```
app.controller('weatherCtrl', ['$scope', 'geolocationService',
    function ($scope, geolocationService) {

        geolocationService.setGeolocation();

        $scope.geolocate = function () {
            $scope.position = geolocationService.getGeolocation();
            // now you can use $scope.position object.
            console.log($scope.position);
        }
    }
]);
```

**geolocationService.js**

```
angular.module('app').service('geolocationService', function () {
    var currentPosition = {};
    geolocationSuccess = function (position) {
        alert(
            'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
            'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n' +
            'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '\n' +
            'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '\n' +
            'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '\n' +
            'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '\n' +
            'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '\n' +
            'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '\n');

        // set any properties you needs
        currentPosition.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        currentPosition.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        // no need to return position here;
    }

    geolocationError = function (error) {
        alert(
            'code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    this.setGeolocation = function (position) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
    }

    this.getGeolocation = function () {
        return currentPosition;
    }

});
```

---

**Deal with Async: Using Promise Approach:**
**weatherCtrl.js**

```
app.controller('weatherCtrl', ['$scope', 'geolocationService',
        function ($scope, geolocationService) {
            $scope.geolocate = function () {
                geolocationService.getGeolocation().then(pos => {
                    $scope.position = pos;
                    console.log($scope.position);
                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err));
            }
        }
    ]);
```

**geolocationService.js**

```
angular.module('app').service('geolocationService', function () {

    this.getGeolocation = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                resolve(position);

            }, function (error) {
                reject(error);
            });
        })
    }
});
```